# jQuery validate submitHandler triggers validation

Tags: jquery, validation

When using the jQuery submitHandler method, I'm posting the form data via ajax to the server. On success, another method is called that resizes a popup and notifies the user its all complete.

My problem is however, whilst posting the data, the form is getting validated again causing undesired effects.

My understanding is submitHandler shouldn't trigger the validation again?

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

In this instance, 'test' is being logged to the console, but the validation is being run once again (in this case, a server side validity check on an email address field).

I'm using a button type submit as the form element. Do I need to prevent defaults or something similar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `submitHandler` should exist within the `validate` function. In addition you should call `form.submit()` yourself which will remove the recursive calls that would otherwise exist.

```js
     $("#myForm").validate({
          submitHandler: function (form) {
              console.log('test');
              form.submit();
          }
     });
```